# Calculating a large number of R-squared statistics in R

Tags: r, regression, r-squared

I have a very large number of R-squared statistics to collect, basically I'm collecting a monthly R-squared series for a period of around 25 years for a large number of variables where I'm interested in how well each of the variables is explained by the mean of the others in the bunch. There are thousands of variables under examination.

I am currently simply doing it like this:

```
fit <- lm(df[,i] ~ me, na.action=na.omit);
rsqPeriod <- summary(fit)$r.squared;
```

where `df[,i]` is the individual one-month series and `me` is the respective series of means of the others. But as there are thousands of variables and a few hundred months, this takes a very long time to calculate. In total, we're talking of several days on a high-end Xeon.

Now the question is, is there a considerably more efficient way of calculating the R-squared values? I do not need any other results from the regressions, and I am wondering if there is e.g. very much unnecessary calculation in the summary function, since I don't need any of the other values.

Comment: if you have only one independent variable then the $R^2$ is the square of the correlation.  Maybe that helps ?

Comment: Using `cor` seems to drop the time spent by around 12%. I'm guessing there's probably no magic tricks that could do it considerably faster than that.

Comment: Have a look at lm.fit (base R) or fastLm from the RcppArmadillo package. But be warned; both are harsh and unforgiving functions. If you make any mistake along they way, they will tell you because they do not check. Also, this question might be a better fit for SO. But I suppose the statistical question is something like: What is the bare minimum needed to calculate an $R^2$ value.

Comment: If me is always the same regressor, you would not need to invert X`X in every regression, I guess.

Comment: @ChristophHanck For each variable `i`, `me` is calculated as the mean of all variables excluding `i` itself, i.e. it's the mean of all the other variables. So it has to be recalculated each time.

Comment: Are you doing any of this in parallel? Seems like a good fit for foreach/doMC. Alternatively could use parallel BLAS to get faster lm fits.

Comment: $R^2$ is unlikely to be of any utility in understanding or analyzing a dataset of this size.  Could you perhaps explain what it is you really want to learn about your data?

Comment: @whuber I'm analyzing stock synchronicity, where $R^2$ is a widely accepted measure of how correlated the movement of stocks are in a market. It's not so much the actual value itself but rather the changes in the value. See the paper "$R^2$" by R. Roll, for example.